# Playing MIDI file in C# from memory

Tags: c#, winapi, midi

How can I play the MIDI file directly from memory (e.g. Resources)?
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905732/how-repeat-a-midi-file-in-c) as a solution, but I do not understand how to play the MIDI from resources. Help me with the right WinAPI command please

Comment: You have to explicitly load the file from the project Resources into memory. It's not clear what part of the linked code isn't working for you.

Comment: private static void _Open(string sFileName) is working for some file on the disk, it is pretty simple. My question is how to call the WinAPI function from the MemoryStream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i made kind of a temporary solution.
Still, it works

```
using (var midiStream = new MemoryStream(Resources.myMidi))
        {
            var data = midiStream.ToArray();
            try
            {
                using (var fs = new FileStream("midi.mid", FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                } 
            }
            catch(IOException)
            {}
            string sCommand = "open \"" + Application.StartupPath + "/midi.mid" + "\" alias " + "MIDIapp";
            mciSendString(sCommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            sCommand = "play " + "MIDIapp";
            mciSendString(sCommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SoundPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.aspx) class:

```
using (Stream midi = Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream("myMidi"))
{
    using (SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(midi))
    {
        player.Play();
    }
}
```

Comment: I got an 'Invalid operation exception' (The value of the specified resource is not a MemoryStream object.) I tried this code:            `using (Stream midi = new MemoryStream(Resources.myMidi))
            {
                using (SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(midi))
                {
                    player.Play();
                }
            }` , but there is an invalid operation exception in the Play() method.. Maybe my MIDI is wrong?

Comment: No, SoundPlayer can only play back WAV, not MIDI.

Comment: At least i saw the same question on MSDN forum, and there it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a .NET library that has playback functionality. [DryWetMIDI](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi) allows this (example shows playing a MIDI file via default Windows synthesizer):

```
var midiFile = MidiFile.Read("Greatest song ever.mid");

// Or you can read a MIDI file from a stream
// var midiFile = MidiFile.Read(stream);

using (var outputDevice = OutputDevice.GetByName("Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth"))
{
    midiFile.Play(outputDevice);
}
```

You can read more about playing MIDI data on the library docs: [Playback](https://melanchall.github.io/drywetmidi/articles/playback/Overview.html).