# How to create a sound from scratch C#

Tags: c#, c++, file, audio, audio-player

I am trying to build a virtual piano in C#, and want a way to create a scale of musical notes from scratch.

I know that I can simply find or create a bunch of .wav files, 1 for each note, but this will create too much space on the User's Hard disk and not be very intuative for myself in the future.

So is there a way to create a proper sound - e.g B flat, in C# without using a .wav file, all in code thorugh c#, and if not, is there a way to do this in a different language - C++.

Thanks, I have tried to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: +1 for a cool question - I know it's possible but I haven't the slightest idea how to do it :) Good luck!

Comment: +1 although `.wav` files don't take much space, there must be a way to do without them

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Note#Note_frequency_.28hertz.29) entry on how to convert musical notes to a frequency you can plug in to your sound generators.

Comment: @Dani agreed, wavs shouldn't be the only way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this looks like it should get you started:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dawate/archive/2009/06/24/intro-to-audio-programming-part-3-synthesizing-simple-wave-audio-using-c.aspx

**EDIT :** I should add that generating sounds without .wav samples and emulating a piano are at odds with each other.

If you want to get a 'real' piano sound, it's best to work with samples (hold them in memory if you don't want to keep them in the filesystem). If you just want a simple way of emitting accurate notes (which sound nothing like a real piano) then doing it programmatically is the way to go!

Comment: Thanks, that seems like the thing I need. I've got a long road ahead!

Comment: @Dommer Thanks, one of mine too. Assuming you're referring to his most famous _Toccata_ of course!

Comment: @Widor I agree, this is mostly an experiment to see how to do this. 1 other point, could you use DirectSound?

Comment: @JBellamy My answer to that would be "yes, you could" but not having done it personally, I'd have to suggest you ask a DirectSound-specific question to get some better answers!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to emulate a piano specifically you only have two options, one of which is to use samples and the other is [physical modelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_modelling_synthesis). Physical modelling requires some pretty advanced knowledge of DSP (filtering, convolution, etc.) and a piano would be a challenging instrument to tackle but it has been done by the likes of [Pianoteq](http://www.pianoteq.com/)

On the subject of samples, to create a piano that is anywhere near a convincing analogue you would ideally require more than one sample per note for different velocities with crossfades between them but you can probably get away with using a sample over a limited range of notes to reduce the total number of samples.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at MIDI.

There's a [windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you could wrap in C++, then expose a managed interface you can consume in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a MIDI library could help? I'm not into the matter, but if you don't want to use audio files it's the only thing that comes to my mind. There's a question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763/best-way-to-play-midi-sounds-using-c-sharp).

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mike4/DotNetPiano11122005012432AM/DotNetPiano.aspx) you find an article including source on how to create piano sound from scratch for at least one Octave worth of musical notes (it is extensible).